# PHP echo Cookies with plus sign or space

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies, space

I have set my cookies `name` with a value with spacing. I have check the cookies value in the browser is `John+Steve`. However echo through the website, it shows `John` only and ignore value after `+`.

```
<?php
      setcookie('name','John Steve');
?>
<?php
      if(isset($_COOKIE['name'])){
         echo $_COOKIE['name']; 
      }
?>
```

I have try echo the cookies with

```
echo rawurldecode($_COOKIE['name']);
```

It still show the same results. Please help me solve this problem and echo it with `John Steve` as well. Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you tried using `setrawcookie` to prevent the automated encoding?

Comment: Hi Alex, I also have try the `setrawcookie`. It will ignore the cookies value with spacing at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try as follows 
`echo  urldecode($_COOKIE['name']);`

Comment: Have try it, but still the same.